# how to pass multiple element in $match(aggregation) in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
db.tst_col.aggregate( { $match : { abc : {1,2,3} }})
```

How to check for the multiple values for the `abc`, like i have to check the value for abc from 1 to 20 in one statement

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any query arguments in the aggregation framework like you can with normal queries, so you can do:

```
db.tst_col.aggregate( { $match: { abc: { $gte: 1, $lte: 20 } } } );
```

If you don't want a range, you can do it as follows:

```
db.tst_col.aggregate( { $match: { abc: { $in: [ 1, 4, 12, 17, 20 ] } } } );
```

Comment: Thanks You!!!@Derick  **and what about if we want to match only for 10 different values in single statement**

Comment: @Jeetu12 `db.d.aggregate({$match:{one:1, two:2 //upto 10 }})` also you should try accepting your answers